# Using TextMate, how can I wrap everything in PHP tags?

Tags: textmate

A question about [TextMate](http://macromates.com/). For example, I just typed `var_dump($codes);`, and I forgot to write `<?php ?>`. So, now I want to highlight the area that I want to wrap the php tags around. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add a new command called for ex 'Wrap in ' in your php bundle editor (Bundles->Bundle Editors->Show Bundle Editor)

In the Activation choose: Key Equivalent and hit: `CMD+SHIFT+W` (or whatever you'd like that's not already taken).

Leave the scope selector to `source.php`

In the snippet window write:

```
<?php  $TM_SELECTED_TEXT ?>
```

Now select anything and hit `CMD+SHIFT+W` and you're done

Sorry I couldn't upload an image to show you I've just signed up.

**EDIT** I now have enough reputation to upload the image:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could select the line your PHP command is on and do a Search and Replace operation with a regular expression. Search for

```
^(.*)$
```

and replace it with

```
<?php $1 ?>
```

as seen in the screen shot. The regular expression will match everything on the line and wrap the PHP tag around it.

[image: TextMate Screenshot]

Comment: Is this fast, especially with big files?

Comment: That I don't know, I'm a BBEdit user myself :) I did download a TextMate demo to figure out that one.

Comment: I was asking because sometimes Textmate is really really slow with regexes, and this looks like it might make it choke.

Comment: That's very possible. I'm kind of a Unix person, so my approach was a little Unix-ish. The other mentioned solutions are obviously better suited for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML bundle has a command to wrap in `<?= ?>`:

[image]

You could assign a keyboard shortcut to this from the Bundle Editor, and if you're so inclined you could even add a new command for `<?php ?>`.